# Algebra problem asking for the sum of two people's ages.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A very simple problem tends to become very hard. Perhaps I am overthinking it.

> If the square of Winslow's age is added to Abby's age, the sum is 209.
>   If the square of Abby's age is added to Winslow's age, the sum if 183.
>   What is the sum of their ages?

I start off as usual by setting equations:

$$w^2+a=209$$ $$w+a^2=183$$

where $w$ and $a$ are Winslow's and Abby's ages, respectively.

Now, I try to solve:

$$w=183-a^2$$$$\implies (183-a^2)^2+a=209$$$$\implies a^4-366a^2+a+33280=0$$

I have no way to continue solving, as I can't set $a^2$ to some variable due to there being an $a$ in the equation. I try to solve it again by substituting for $w$ but still get the very complicated equation.

Desperate, I try adding the equations together:

$$\implies w^2+w+a^2+a=392$$$$\implies w(w+1)+a(a+1)=392$$

Here, I become stuck again, as I cannot factor this thing further into the form $(a+b)(c+d)$.

How do I solve this problem? Have I missed a point?

Thanks!

Max0815

Comment: This may not help but I did it by inspection and got $w=14$ and $a=13$.

Comment: Inspection may be the best way to go here.

Comment: Hint? The question asks for the sum of the ages, not the ages themselves. I  _think_ if you add the equations and subtract them you will be on your way.

Comment: @EthanBolker I'm not sure how adding the equation and then subtracting it again will do any help as I currently understand your hint, because doing that will just reverse the adding.

Comment: @Matt I see. Mind to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the equations, you could subtract them:

$209-183=w^2+a-a^2-w=(w+a)(w-a)+(a-w)=(w-a)(w+a-1).$

Since $209-183=26=13 \cdot 2=1\cdot 26$, and $w+a-1 > w-a$, we have that either $w+a-1=26$ or that $w+a-1=13$. But since $w$ and $a$ must have different parity (if they had the same parity, $w^2+a$ and $a^2+w$ would be even, which is not the case), their sum must be odd, meaning that we can rule out the $w+a=14$ case. Therefore, $w+a=27$.

(I have edited this comment, I dont know if that is something that I am supposed to mention, but now I have).

Answer (score 1):

Ages must be positive whole numbers, so the sums give us bounds:

$a^2$ must be less than $183$, so $a$ $<$ $14$.

$w^2$ must be less than 209, so $w$ $<$ $15$.

Testing the highest possible pair gives us a solution:

$$14^2+13=209$$

$$13^2+14=183$$